# How to access inner variable of a function and change its value in python?

Tags: python

```
>>> def nil():
...     ss='nil'
...     print ss
... 
>>> nil()
nil
>>> nil.ss='kk'
>>> nil()
nil
>>> print nil.ss
kk
```

I know everything is an object in python, so function is also an object, now I wanna change the value of 'ss' variable, which is stored in function , now I tried to change its value by using nil.ss but it didn;t change..What is the diff between both 'ss'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `ss` is an inner variable of the function; the second one is an attribute of the function. They don't reference the same object.

Here's a way to do it, though:

```
>>> def apple():
    if not hasattr(apple, 'ss'):  # This way it'll only be set inside the function once
        apple.ss = 'nil'
    return apple.ss

>>> apple()
'nil'
>>> apple.ss
'nil'
>>> apple.ss = 'kk'
>>> apple.ss
'kk'
>>> apple()
'kk'
```

Answer (score 3):

The function is an object, but `ss` is not a member variable in the sense it would be in a class. It is a local variable defined in the body of the function and is not accessible outside. The only sane way to change it would be to change the implementation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
def nil():
 ss='nil'
```

it's because `nil.ss` doesn't point to the varible `ss` defined in the `nil` function.

`nil.ss` means `ss` is now a attribute of the `nil` object.

`nil.ss` and `ss` inside `nil()` are completely different.

```
>>> def nil():
    ss='foo'
    return ss

>>> nil.ss='bar'
>>> foo=nil()
>>> bar=nil()
>>> nil.ss
'bar'
>>> foo
'foo'
>>> bar
'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ss` that you create within the body of the function is only a temporary variable; it doesn't exist until that line of code is executed, and it ceases to exist once the end of the block is reached.

The `ss` that you create on the function is an attribute of the function. Now you you have two different variables named `ss` but they have nothing at all to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the other part of your question: you cannot change the local variable `ss` from outside the function.  It doesn't exist except when the function is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code using the compiler module. It will allow you to load up arbitrary python code as text, parse it into an Abstract Syntax Tree, make alterations to it, and then recompile it. Afterwhich you can run the code with the additional changes.

http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html

Though I wouldn't suggest using it as it's deprecated in Python 3.0. There may be other ways to do this in 3.0 as they wouldn't have deprecated the module otherwise.

One really has to ask. What weirdly odd scenario are you trying to solve with this method that you're trying to write? Chances are that whatever it is that you need to do, you can do it in a much simpler way. Either by way of parameters to the function, or a class structure that you design to fit your needs.